# How do I retrieve a list of just the annotated tags with git?

Tags: git

`git tag` and `git show-ref --tags` list all tags. I don't see an flag for specifying **only annotated** tags.

Comment: `git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format '%(objecttype) %(refname:short)' | awk '$1 == "tag" {print $2}'`